# Populate select field with database data based on another select field using jQuery in Cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.7

Am using CakePHP 2.7.3 and jQuery v2.1.4. I have a borrows controller add action that accepts `subject_id` and `book_id`. I need the `book_id` form select to have only books that belong to the selected `subject_id`. So far i don't have any idea on how to do it, i've tried  searching online but most possible answers are insufficient for my case. Kindly Assist with the jQuery part.

This is my Html:

```
<div class="borrows form">
<form action="/borrows/add" id="BorrowAddForm" method="post" accept-    charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div> <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Borrow</legend>
    <div class="input select required"><label  for="BorrowSubjectId">Subject</label><select name="data[Borrow][subject_id]" id="BorrowSubjectId" required="required">
<option value="100">English</option>
<option value="101">Kiswahili</option>
<option value="102">Maths</option>
<option value="103">Biology</option>
<option value="109">Business Studies</option>
<option value="110">Agriculture</option>
<option value="111">Computer Studies</option>
</select></div>
```

and:

```
<div class="input select required"><label  for="BorrowBookId">Book</label><select name="data[Borrow][book_id]" onClick="return false" id="BorrowBookId" required="required">
<option value="1">Huber, Graiden A.</option>
<option value="2">Banks, Isadora N.</option>
<option value="3">Richard, Bianca W.</option>
<option value="4">Dyer, Dennis I.</option>
<option value="5">Barrera, Rafael D.</option>
<option value="6">Gilliam, Eden A.</option>
</select></div>
```

Comment: There are plenty of examples on SO and elsewhere on how to achieve this. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367793/how-to-retrive-data-in-cakephp-when-change-the-options-of-a-select-fields?rq=1

Comment: @Oops I just got an idea.... let me try it first and see how it works

Comment: @Inigo thanks. That's helps alot